# Linq to ldap User Model resturns Server instead of user

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory, linq-to-ldap

I am using [LinqToLdap](http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com) and tried to find all users from our AD by using the example provided by LinqToLdap. But with no success. First I tried to modify the Model to better fit our AD

```
[DirectorySchema("DC=corp,DC=intern", ObjectClass = "User")]
public class User : DirectoryObjectBase{
    [DistinguishedName]
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute("cn", ReadOnly = true)]
    public string CommonName { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute(StoreGenerated = true)]
    public Guid ObjectGuid { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute(StoreGenerated = true)]
    public SecurityIdentifier ObjectSid { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute("memberOf", ReadOnly = true)]
    public Collection<string> GroupMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

And query with

```
public class LinqToLdapProvider{
    private LdapConfiguration _cfg;
    public LinqToLdapProvider(string domain){
        _cfg = new LdapConfiguration();
        _cfg.ConfigurePooledFactory(domain)
                .MinPoolSizeIs(1)
                .MaxPoolSizeIs(50)
                .AuthenticateAs(new NetworkCredential("MyDomain.Username","MySecretPAssword"));
    }
    public void Query(){
        using (var context = new DirectoryContext(_cfg)) {
            context.Log = Console.Out;
            var user = context.Query<User>(); // I expected this to return all users
        }
    }
}
```

But as result I got a very huge list containing all Servers and other stuff... I tried to find more information within the documentation and tried to modify the DirectorySchema Attribbute of User class bit with no luck.

Here is the path that I tried to query where the users are the ones with the green strokes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific with your mapping.  Either change your naming context to your user OU or add ObjectClass="User" ObjectCategory="Person" to your schema mapping.  See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198834.aspx) for more information.